# How to match string after specific string or same string if not

Tags: regex

in this regex https://regex101.com/r/4HnCo0/1

i wanna match those strings

```
hello 2020
hello 2020 new year
hello 2020 - new year
world
world year of 2020
world - year of 2020
```

and get matches of

```
hello 2020
new year
new year
world
year of 2020
year of 2020
```

if it is `hello \d+` alone then get it all - if not then get everything after it

and if it is the word `world` alone then get everything after it - if not then `world` only

i tried `(?:(?:hello \d+(?:\W+)?|world\W+))?(.+)` but it gets me

```
0
new year
new year
world
year of 2020
year of 2020
```

**(remove in link and use 1 line only for real results)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an alternation to match the tail, in all its variants, otherwise just the naked prefixes:

```
(?<=hello \d{4} )(?!- ).*|(?<=hello \d{4} - ).*| (?<=world )(?!- ).*|(?<=world - ).*|(hello \d{4}|world)$
```

See [live demo](https://rubular.com/r/PORfbqq99KRF9G).